# Copy all lines of a console app screen to text file

Tags: c#, logging, console

I have a console application that does a lot of logging to screen via `Console.Writeline`.

Short of converting each `Console.Writeline` to a file write, or buffering each `console.Writeline` to a `StringBuilder`,

is there a way to take a full dump of the console screen lines to a text file when the application runs to the end?

Comment: simple way : application.exe >>log.txt

Comment: You could create a list of string and when you are writing to the console by `Console.Writeline` and after this line you also add it to the list and at the end of the program you got a list with all the output that you can now write at the end of the program.

Comment: @Cal-cium that would still require me to go through the entire code and add more code to each console.writeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1- Redirect Console.WriteLine to a file:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Output.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
System.Console.SetOut(sw);
```

(PS. If you do so, don't forget to set the Console output back and close the stream before the program terminates)

2- When running your executable, direct the output to a file, for example:

```
C:\>MyExecutable.exe > C:\Output.txt
```

Comment: Second Option is the simplest. No code modification required

Answer (score 1):

```
  FileStream ostrm;
            StreamWriter writer;
            TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
            try
            {
                ostrm = new FileStream("./Redirect.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }
            Console.SetOut(writer);
            Console.WriteLine("This is a line of text");
            Console.WriteLine("Everything written to Console.Write() or");
            Console.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine() will be written to a file");
            Console.SetOut(oldOut);
            writer.Close();
            ostrm.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

use can use `Console.SetOut()` to set the output

nice example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/DemonstratesredirectingtheConsoleoutputtoafile.htm

Comment: This basically commes down to writing the screen logs one by one. thats what i whant to avoid

Comment: This would require me to search out the `Console.Writeline` everywhere and then add `Console.SetOut`

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu, no you do not have to search all the Console.Writeline and add Console.SetOut. Add it in the main or globally

Comment: oh ok, so I only need Console.setOut once

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu, Yes you are correct. Please refer the link for the nice example